# Spring Boot - Web Sockets - Test

Tags: java, spring, testing, websocket, junit

I have a simple server in the Spring Boot. I want to implement and test my web socket connection, but If I want to subscripe end-point '/topic/resources', timeout is out after 30s. The message send correct, and function callFunction() in the controller is called. Would you happen to know why it does not work?

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/{classType}/{functionName}")
    @SendTo("/topic/resources")
    public String callFunction(
            @DestinationVariable String classType,
            @DestinationVariable String functionName,
            Optional<Map<String, Object>> params
    ) {
        return classType + " " + functionName;
    }
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/management").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/call");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ManagementFrameworkApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class WebSocketTest {

    private CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void testCreateGameEndpoint() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(new SockJsClient(createTransportClient()));
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        StompSession stompSession = stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:" + port + "/management", new StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {})
                .get(5, SECONDS);

        final var params = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        params.set("numbers", objectMapper.createArrayNode().add(1).addNull().add(2));
        params.put("operator", Operator.ADD.name());

        stompSession.subscribe("/topic/resources", new StringStompFrameHandler());
        stompSession.send("/call/CalculatorMResource/sum", params);

        String string = completableFuture.get(30, SECONDS); // here is Timeout!

        System.out.println(string);
    }

    private List<Transport> createTransportClient() {
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(1);
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
        return transports;
    }

    private class StringStompFrameHandler implements StompFrameHandler {
        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders stompHeaders, Object o) {
            completableFuture.complete((String) o);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the missing `StringMessageConverter` registration for the `WebSocketStompClient` in your test. Your websocket endpoints returns a plain string which the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` can't convert as this converter is only responsible for `application/json`.

Try this instead:

```java
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(new SockJsClient(createTransportClient()));
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
```